# WAMP server: Local host not working?

Tags: php, windows, wamp

When i click on the local host tab of my WAMP server it opens up the webpage but gives a blank page with the following error:

```
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

I have researched online about the problem and uninstalled Skype and turned off my firewall as suggested. However it did not solve it.

What else can be done to solve the issue?

note: The WAMP server is online, yet the icon is still red. I am using a windows 64 bit laptop.

EDIT:

When I "test port 80" within the apache tab I get the following screen:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on again?

Comment: I'd start by checking the error logs and seeing if there are any startup errors.

Comment: I turned my laptop on and off is thats what u mean

Comment: Where do you see the error logs? Sorry I am very new to working with a server

Comment: what happens when you right click the red icon and select "restart all services"?

Comment: I tried to restart all services but it did not make a difference, please see my edit as I think that may be the problem, thanks

Comment: If the wampmanager icon is RED, then Apache and MySQL have not started. So nothing will work. Look at your windows Event Viewer for error messages from Apache and MySQL. if you dont understand the messages EDIT your question and post the mesages there for us to see.

Comment: In that case you have IIS installed and running. If you are not using IIS then uninstall it. There are instructions on the web.

Comment: I checked in my control panel, under "Turn windows features on or off" , ISS is not checked as being on?

Comment: How about SQL Server or Web Deploy or BranchCache

Comment: I think I have web deploy?

Comment: Disable that in services.msc so it is not grabbing port 80. That way you can turn it back on if you need it else where

Comment: Thank you, I think I have cleared port 80 by disabling web deploy. However, now instead of my orignal error I just get "Google chrome could not connect to local host" instead?

Comment: Try another browser, some versions of Chrome have an issue with `localhost` for some reason. Firefox should work. What colour is your wampmanager icon now? It should be GREEN

Comment: The icon is still red although I have cleared the port?

Comment: Should I delete MYSQL server>

Comment: Hang on, in services do yuo have a service called `Apache` as well as a `wampapache` and `MYSQL` as well as `wampmysql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the Web Deployment Agent Service (MsDepSvc) service running on your machine?  Disable it and restart, see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have cleared port 80 by disabling web deploy. However, now instead of my orignal error I just get "Google chrome could not connect to local host" instead?

Comment: Has it ever worked?  Does your  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file have an entry for localhost going to 127.0.0.1 that isn't commented out?

Comment: Im not sure I cant seem to open the file>

Comment: Its a protected file, launch your editor (preferably not notepad) using `Run as Administrator` then you can save changes

Comment: You have to run Notepad++ or whatever as an account with admin permisisons to the local machine to edit it.